# How to improve collision detection performance on complex geometry by using tree data structures?

Tags: javascript, three.js, binary-search-tree, collision-detection

I have built a VR application similar to [WebVR-Vive-Dragging](https://threejs.org/examples/#webvr_vive_dragging) that allows to interact with numerous 3d objects using VR controllers. This means that a user can grab an object with a VR controller and can move or scale it.

In my application, a collision detection mechanism finds the correct `THREE.Mesh` object the user is currently touching with a VR controller. At first, it iterates over all 3d objects in the scene comparing their bounding spheres with the controller's bounding sphere. Overlapping objects are then tested with `THREE.Raycaster` to find the appropriate object. I have setup three `THREE.Ray` objects on each VR controller to achieve this.

**Problem**: When there are complex 3d objects in the scene, i.e. `THREE.Mesh` objects having geometries with a very large number of vertices, then the raycasting during the collision detection gets very slow. Hence, my problem is NOT the number of 3d objects in the scene but the complexity of the geometry of one object.

I have searched for a way to split up an object's geometry into a set of bounding boxes with references to the containing vertices. This would allow to test the boxes first. The containing vertices could be used for raycasting afterwards.

There are tree data structures for fast spatial search, such as [Octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) or [R-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree). I have found [threeocttree](https://github.com/collinhover/threeoctree) that allows to split up a geometry into smaller chunks but it seems that it is a bit out of date (Three.js r60).

**My Question**: Does anybody know a better solution than my current raycasting approach for collision detection? Is there a way to build a complex geometry splitting in Three.js in order to achieve faster collision detection? If not, maybe it could be helpful in future Three.js versions to have such an internal geometry decomposition to allow faster search.

Comment: In c++, I wrote an adaptive grid that does 40k aabb vs 40k aabb collision pair list in 40ms and 100k dynamic aabb vs 8000 static aabb collision list in 10ms. What is your performance? How many collisions?

Answer (score 3):

Octrees are the easiest solutions I personally find for these problems where you need to accelerate raycasts for complex meshes. Some alternatives are BVH, K-D tree, and R-Tree.

You can store a separate octree with each non-trivial mesh so that you don't have to update one for an entire scene. Also if your objects are just being transformed, not deformed, then you don't even need to update the octree stored with the mesh. You can just transform the ray with the inverse of the transformation matrix for the object prior to testing for intersections against the AABBs in the octree.

I have also segmented meshes spanning millions of polygons and vertices the way you have proposed before using a number of techniques ranging from k-means clustering to octrees (using them to determine the segmentation rather than accelerate spatial queries) to segmenting meshes based on connectivity/adjacency data. That said, I did that to reduce cache misses on mesh traversal, rendering, and to allow for a localized form of "sub-mesh LOD". For just picking, raycasting, and collision-detection, I'd recommend using a spatial index like an octree or BVH so that you don't have to test every single triangle, e.g.